# Removing class if click outside of div (targetting class)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a menu where user clicks on link and list appears via `.addClass( "show-nav" )`.

Here is [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ghLn4nmL/1/) with JS code:

```
jQuery(".nav-js-trigger").each(function(){
    this.onclick = function() {

        var hasClass;
        hasClass = jQuery(this).next().hasClass( "show-nav" );

        jQuery('.show-nav').removeClass('show-nav');

        if (hasClass === false) {
            jQuery(this).next().addClass( "show-nav" );
        }

    }
});
```

I want to remove the class `show-nav` if the user clicks **outside** of the div with class `show-nav`. **How do I do this?**

I have seen examples of `e.target` div ID but not class, particularly not a scenario like this.

Comment: Post a complete code example in your question please.

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element?rq=1

Answer (score 5):

You can add an listener to the element with an `event.stopPropagation()` on it, and another listener to the body, to capture this event if not intercepted before.

Something like this:

```
$(".show-nav").on("click", function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});

$("body").on("click", function(event){
    $(".show-nav").hide(); // or something...
});
```

To simplify your use-case, here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aokeo0y0/1/).

```js
$(".trigger").on("click", function(event)
{
    $(".menu").toggle();
    event.stopPropagation();
});

$(".menu").on("click", function(event)
{
    event.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).on("click", function(event)
{
    $(".menu").hide();
});
```

```css
.menu
{
    display: none;
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="trigger">menu</a>
<div class="menu">Hello</div>
```

Comment: Can you please update the fiddle? I tried adding your code but it did not work unfortunately: http://jsfiddle.net/ghLn4nmL/2/

Comment: @HenrikPetterson, added jsfiddle and code snippet... I've changed your a bit (ok, a lot) to make it simpler and more flexible...

Comment: Thank you very much for the update, although now you can't hide the div when you click on menu again. If you see my original fiddle and click on menu twice, you will know what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/ghLn4nmL/1/ -- I will bounty this question with 50 points once it is eligible.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson, not a problem... Just updated the code again, changing the `.show()` to `.toggle()` in the `$(".trigger")` click listener... Could you try it again?

Comment: Excellent, although I do have one final request. The code needs to use it's original approach of adding the show-nav class to div. Is this still possible with your approach?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("click", function(e) {  if ($(e.target).is(".trigger") === false) {
      $(".menu").hide();
    }
  });
```